# Laravel view content showing twice for routes with parameters

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am working with Laravel 5.5, I have two get routes with parameters like this

`Route::get( 'route/{parameter}', 'Controller@action' )->name( 'controller.action' );`

My controller action is simply loading the view:

```
public function action( $slug ) {
    return view( 'view', [
        'post' => Post::whereSlug( $slug )->first()
    ] );
}
```

My base app.blade.php view content is:

```
<!-- ==========================
  PAGE WRAPPER
=========================== -->
<div class="page-wrapper">

    <!-- ==========================
          HEADER
        =========================== -->
    <header class="header" id="header">

        <!-- Hamburger -->
        <div class="h-hamburger" id="hamburger">
            <svg class="h-hamburger__icon">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-hamburger"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="h-logo">
            <a href="{{route('dashboard')}}" title="{{config('app.name','Sensei U')}}">
                <img class="h-logo__img" src="{{URL::to('/')}}/images/logo-black.svg"
                     alt="{{ config('app.name', 'Sensei U') }}">
            </a>
        </div>

    @if (Auth::user())

        <!-- Welcome -->
            <div class="h-welcome">

                <!-- Title -->
                <div class="h-welcome__title">Welcome Back, {{Auth::user()->name}}</div>

                <!-- Date -->
                <div class="h-welcome__date">{{date('F j')}}</div>

                <!-- Time -->
                <div class="h-welcome__time">{{date('g:i a')}}</div>

            </div>
            <!-- Profile -->
            <div class="h-profile">

                <!-- Avatar -->
                <img class="h-profile__avatar"
                     src="{{Auth::user()->image ? SenseiU::getImagePathBySize(Storage::url(Auth::user()->image), 58, 58) : ''}}"
                     srcset="{{Auth::user()->image ? SenseiU::getImagePathBySize(Storage::url(Auth::user()->image), 116, 116) : ''}} 2x"
                     alt="{{Auth::user()->name}}">
            @if(($notifications = SenseiU::generateNotificationMessages( Auth::user() )) )
                <!-- Notifications -->
                    <button class="h-profile__notifications" data-uid="{{Auth::user()->id}}"
                            data-url="{{route('member.nr', [Auth::user()])}}">
                        {{count($notifications)}}
                    </button>
                @endif

            </div>

        @if($notifications)

            <!-- Notifications Dropdown -->
                <ul class="noti-dropdown">
                    @foreach($notifications as $notification)
                        <li class="noti-dropdown__item">
                            <a class="noti-dropdown__link" href="{{$notification['link']}}">
                                {{$notification['msg']}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        @endif

    </header>
    <!-- ==========================
      CONTENT WRAPPER
    =========================== -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- ==========================
          SIDEBAR
        =========================== -->
        <aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <!-- Menu -->
            <nav class="sidebar-menu">
                @if(Auth::user())
                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'dashboard' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('dashboard')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Home</span>
                    </a>

                    @permission('daily-mastery')
                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item  {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.daily-mastery' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.daily-mastery')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Daily Mastery</span>

                        @if(SenseiU::getPageNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), [
                        'App\Notifications\TipPublishedNotification',
                        'App\Notifications\ExerciseSchedulePublishedNotification'] ))

                            <span class="sidebar-menu__notifications">{{SenseiU::getPageNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), [
                        'App\Notifications\TipPublishedNotification',
                        'App\Notifications\ExerciseSchedulePublishedNotification'] )}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </a>
                    @endpermission

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.macros' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.macros')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Macros Calculator</span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.instructional-videos' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.instructional-videos')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Instructional Videos</span>
                        @if(SenseiU::getPageNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), [
                        'App\Notifications\VideoPublishedNotification'] ))
                            <span class="sidebar-menu__notifications">{{SenseiU::getPageNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), [
                        'App\Notifications\VideoPublishedNotification'] )}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </a>

                    @permission('health-articles')
                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.nutrition' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.nutrition')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Nutrition</span>
                        @if(SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 2 ))
                            <span class="sidebar-menu__notifications">{{SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 2 )}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </a>

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.sports-injuries' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.sports-injuries')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Sports Injuries</span>
                        @if(SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 3 ))
                            <span class="sidebar-menu__notifications">{{SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 3 )}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </a>

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.mobility-stretching' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.mobility-stretching')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Mobility & Stretching</span>
                        @if(SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 4 ))
                            <span class="sidebar-menu__notifications">{{SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 4 )}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </a>

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.functional-training' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.functional-training')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Functional Training</span>
                        @if(SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 5 ))
                            <span class="sidebar-menu__notifications">{{SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 5 )}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </a>

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.articles' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.articles')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Articles</span>
                        @if(SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 1 ))
                            <span class="sidebar-menu__notifications">{{SenseiU::getArticleSectionNotificationsCount( Auth::user(), 1 )}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </a>
                    @endpermission

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.faqs' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.faqs')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">FAQs</span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item" href="#">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Ultimate Personal Trainer</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'member.profile.edit' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('member.profile.edit')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Edit Profile</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item" href="{{URL::to('logout')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Logout</span>
                    </a>
                @else
                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'login' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('login')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Login</span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="sidebar-menu__item {{Route::currentRouteName() == 'register' ? 'sidebar-menu__item--active' : ''}}"
                       href="{{route('register')}}">
                        <span class="sidebar-menu__title">Register</span>
                    </a>
                @endif
            </nav>

        </aside>


        <!-- ==========================
              CONTENT
            =========================== -->
        <main class="content @yield('main-class')">
            <!-- Container -->
            <div class="@yield('container-class')">
                @if(session('msg'))
                    <div class="msg msg-{{session('status')}}">
                        {{session('msg')}}
                    </div>
                @endif
                @yield('content')
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

My view content is like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', $title)
@section('container-class', 'container')

@section('content')
    @if($post)
        <div class="cover" style="background-image:url('{{Storage::url($post->file)}}');"></div>
        <article class="article__container">
            <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
            <div>{!!$post->text!!}</div>
        </article>
    @endif
@stop
```

The problem is that my view content is showing duplicated, one 404 on top of the actual view content like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you include your `layouts.app` or the master layout file?

Comment: It's the default layout file in Laravel, this issue is only showing in routes with parameters only.

Comment: Ok, so what page should exactly appear? the 404 page or the content?

Comment: The content page should appear

Comment: Alright. Can you include this view `@extends('layouts.app')` ?

Comment: I am extending this view in my views

Comment: I know it is, however can you put or include the exact code in your question? so we can figure it out if the problem is in the view you're extending.

Comment: @Hash thank you, the issue was in the layout, but I wasn't able to add all the code because the question must have more description so I cut some of the code, you can check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and I will leave an answer for future reference, the problem wasn't with Laravel, it was a javascript issue, I had this code on the head:

```
    <script>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.open('GET', '/images/sprites.svg', true);

    ajax.send();

    ajax.onload = function (e) {

        var div = document.createElement('div');

        div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;

        document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.childNodes[0]);

    };
</script>
```

which loads an svg sprite and insert it into the page to be used, the ajax url was returning a 404 on routes with parameters, so a 404 page was showing above the views, I fixed it by using an absolute url like this:

```
ajax.open('GET', '{{URL::to('/')}}/images/sprites.svg', true);
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the slug of your Posts. If you include special characters in the slug Laravel won't automatically be able to resolve this, because it assumes it's another URL. I assume you're trying to view a post which has a slug like `my/first/post`, this will work if you include a where statement at the route. You would have to do something like this:

```
Route::get('route/{parameter}', 'Controller@action')
    ->name('controller.action')
    ->where('parameter', '([A-Za-z0-9\-\/]+)');
```

This way the route will include a regex, which validates if the complete string is valid.

I don't know why it would display both the post and a 404 page, it looks like your just including the default 404 page in `layouts.app`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, I also tried using the id as a parameter still the same issue, also I am not including any other views in my app layout template

Comment: Could you check what kind of response the page gives? Does it return a 200 or 404 response?

Comment: Then it seems like the page loads fine, but it also includes the 404 page. We can't really debug how your views look like, and it seems like there's something not right in your views. As mentioned by @hash, can you post the contents of `layouts.app` here, because it seems that's the part where it fails.

Comment: Added in original post